# scrape specific table with div that hold the text with scrapy

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, scrapy

I am using scrapy to scrape the content from a website in a table.

example of the code:

```
            <tr>
                <td><div>2018/2058</div></td>
                <td class="address"><div>Land North of 37 and 39 Hare Lane Claygate Esher Surrey KT10 9BT</div></td>
                <td class="proposal"><div>Confirmation of Compliance with Conditions: 5 (Tree Protection and Pre-Commencement Inspection) and 6 (Tree Protection) of planning permission 2017/0451.</div></td>
                <td><div style="min-width:90px">Claygate Ward</div></td>
            </tr>
```

But as you can see the text is inside a div in each "tr" tag, how would I get the text using xpath or css selector?

Ive tried

```
 yield {

     'applicaition-number':response.xpath('//div[contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@id), " "), " atWeeklyListTable ")]//td[ @class="selectorgadget_selected"]/div/text()').extract_first(),

     'address': response.xpath('//div[contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@id), " "), " atWeeklyListTable ")]//td[ @class="address selectorgadget_suggested"]/div/text()').extract_first(),

    'proposal': response.xpath('//div[contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@id), " "), " atWeeklyListTable ")]//td[ @class="proposal selectorgadget_suggested"]/div/text()').extract_first(),
  }
```

this is the website:

[http://emaps.elmbridge.gov.uk/ebc_planning.aspx?requesttype=parsetemplate&template=WeeklyListAVDetailTab.tmplt&basepage=ebc_planning.aspx&Filter=^id^=%271%27&history=8a016b5504894a589b75179582da69ca&todatetext:PARAM=06%20July%202018&count:PARAM=63&id:PARAM=1&pagerecs=500&maxrecs=500](http://emaps.elmbridge.gov.uk/ebc_planning.aspx?requesttype=parsetemplate&template=WeeklyListAVDetailTab.tmplt&basepage=ebc_planning.aspx&Filter=%5Eid%5E=%271%27&history=8a016b5504894a589b75179582da69ca&todatetext:PARAM=06%20July%202018&count:PARAM=63&id:PARAM=1&pagerecs=500&maxrecs=500)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How did you try to get text?

Comment: Ive updated it to show how I tried getting the text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
first_td_text = response.xpath('//tr[1]/td[1]/div/text()').extract_first()
```

**UPDATE**

```
'address': response.xpath('//td[@class="address"]/div/text()').extract_first(),
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the xpath from gangabass:

```
import scrapy

class txt_filter:
     txt= '<tr>\
                     <td><div>2018/2058</div></td>\
                     <td class="address"><div>Land North of 37 and 39 Hare Lane Claygate Esher Surrey KT10 9BT</div></td>\
                     <td class="proposal"><div>Confirmation of Compliance with Conditions: 6 (Tree Protection and Pre-Commencement Inspection) and 6 (Tree Protection) of planning permission 2017/0451.</div></td>\
                     <td><div style="min-width:90px">Claygate Ward</div></td>\
                </tr>'
     resp = scrapy.http.response.text.TextResponse(body=txt,url='abc',encoding='utf-8')
     print(resp.xpath('//tr[1]/td/div/text()').extract())
```

Only removed the [1] from the td to get all lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily using pandas.

```
table = pd.read_html(url)
```

Now the table is a dataframe that contains the full table